# Replace a # character with a space and a # character

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I am trying to add a space in front of pound sign #.  But it should not add spaces if there is already a space in front of the pound sign.  Also, it should not add a space as the first character of a string.  This is what I have so far:

```
string result = Regex.Replace("542#452", @"(?=#)(?!$)", " ");
```

But this is adding double spaces (when a pound sign already has a space).  It is also adding a space in the beginning:

Sample data and desired output:

```
Input        Output
243#423      243 #423
22 #44       22 #44
#32#         #32 #
#            #
##           # #
```

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assert what is on the left is a non whitespace char `\S` and then match the pound sign and replace with a space and `#`

```
(?<=\S)#
```

For example

```
string result = Regex.Replace("542#452", @"(?<=\S)#", " #");
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cS%29%23&i=542%23452%0d%0a+%23542452%0d%0a%23542452%0d%0a243%23423%0d%0a22+%2344%0d%0a%2332%23%0d%0a%23%0d%0a%23%23&r=+%23) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/oKKrz4)

[image]

Comment: Looks like `C# demo` link is missing a query string

Comment: @AndersonPimentel You are right, I added the wrong link. I have updated the answer.